# ... in php function parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I was reading an article for creating Roles and Permissions in laravel. There I saw three dots `...` inside function parentheses like

```
public function hasRole(... $roles ) {
```

I could not understand what is the purpose of three dots `...` here.

Example Link: https://www.larashout.com/laravel-roles-and-permissions

```
/**
 * @param mixed ...$roles
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasRole(... $roles ) {
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if ($this->roles->contains('slug', $role)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special Unary operator of PHP called "Spread operator" which allows you to have variable-length parameters in a method i.e. the method can take 0 or more parameters for the variable-length parameter.

Below is an example for better understanding:

E.g.

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
 }

echo "\n".sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
echo "\n".sum(1);
echo "\n".sum();
```

Output:

```
10
1
0
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list